# No internet connection to OpenStack Nova VM instance

Tags: networking, openstack, openstack-nova

I have a basic DevStack setup. I am using Ubuntu cloud images. The machine on which I have DevStack set up is having internet connectivity. But when I log into an instance and run `apt-get update`, it came to my fore that the instance do not have internet connectivity. Am I missing a step to allow access to the VM? What exactly is that step?
PS: I have assigned a floating IP to the instance. That is all I have done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `ifconfig` return the correct IPs?

If everything is fine, try checking your system's routing status by `route`. Your Linux may have chosen a wrong default gateway for you.
See http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-setup-default-gateway-with-route-command/

Comment: @RushiAgrawal can you please tell us what exact steps you took. I am also facing the same issue

Comment: Actually it was working for me on my Physical Ubuntu machine, but when I tried the same on a DevStack installation on an Ubuntu 'virtual' machine, I was having errors. I havent looked into the problem yet..sorry